# Handling the same try catch structure in every controller

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I am using Symfony2 for my web project, and I have several controllers that have exactly the same try catch block

```
<?php

class MyBaseController extends Controller {
    private $manager = new MyManager();
    // Some generic stuff
}

class MyController1 extends MyBaseController {
    try {
        $manager->one();        
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->someOtherMessage();
    }
}

class MyController2 extends MyBaseController {
    try {
        $manager->two();        
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->someOtherMessage();
    }
}

class MyController3 extends MyBaseController {
    try {
        $manager->three();      
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->someOtherMessage();
    }
}
```

How could I write this to avoid so much duplication?

Comment: They are just different methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every controller may send a specific exception, you shouldn't need a try/catch block for each method in your controller.
I see two ways to handle this.

First, if this is a global exception which can be thrown, and you just want to render another message than the default 500 error message. You can [override](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) the default template given, by creating your own `error500.html.twig` in your `app/Resources` folder

Another way to handle it is to create a custom exception tied with an [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html).
I would create my own exception like `ManagerException` which will be handled by the event listener.

```
class ManagerException extends Exception {}
```

Your manager(s) would now throw this exception instead.
*Note: You can create any exception you want as long as it extends this base exception*

```
class RuntimeManagerException extends ManagerException {}
```

Then you can declare your event listener

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    manager_exception.listener:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Listener\ManagerExceptionListener
        arguments: [ @templating ]
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: kernel.exception
                method: onKernelException
```

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\Listener\ManagerExceptionListener**</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ManagerExceptionListener
{
    protected $twig;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if (!($exception instanceof ManagerException)) {
            return;
        }

        $response = new Response;
        $response->setContent($this->twig->render('errorpage.html.twig'));

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the services.yml file right? Usually I have seen the "class", "arguments" and "tags" with 2 levels of indentation from services...